# What is recommended way to perform async tasks in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous

Are there any standard tools, or recommended approaches for async tasks execution?

UPD I understand, how to use threads. I only need to know the recommended WPF way to block UI while performing async call, and how to update progress info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use several ways, for example:

- [Thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)
- Plain old threads

And since .NET 4, the preferred way is to use `Tasks`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below post, it describes a way to create an async delegate command(using `BackgroundWorker`). I have used this kind of command in our application and it works fine and at the same time it provides a consistent way of doing things asynchronously.

> An Asynchronous Delegate Command for
>   your WPF MVVM Apps -
>   AsyncDelegateCommand
>   http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/10/asynchronous-delegate-command-for-your.html
>
> A similar implementation is also mentioned here -
>   [Asynchronous WPF Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151686/asynchronous-wpf-commands)

Answer (score 0):

depends what you are trying to do async.
e.g. calling a WCF service I'd use the build-in way, with the Completed pattern that does the marshalling for you.
Normal Background work I'd use the BackgroundWorker as you again don't need to worry about the marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to standard threads. One thing to use are Async methods of many classes, that can do it. This includes web service requests, file read/write operations.

One thing to look at is Coroutines, used mainly by [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) . But its not standard way to do it.

Also .NET 4 adds Task class along with ParallelExtensions, that is capable to do some async programming easier. But its still clumsy, so .NET 5 adds async programing model, to make thigs even easier. But god knows when its going to be released.